# Android - How can I be notified when a certain frame in a gif is displayed?

Tags: android

I'm displaying an animated gif in an ImageView, and a transparent background TextView on top of that. I want to be able to dynamically change the text in the TextView based on the current frame being displayed in the animation. Is there a mechanism to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. I implemented Drawable.ICallback and then use AnimationDrawable.GetFrame() to set the callback on each frame I need.

```
private class MyFragment : DialogFragment, Drawable.ICallback
{
    TextView tv;  /* this is later defined in OnCreateDialog */
    ...

    /* Must implement */
    public void InvalidateDrawable(Drawable who)
    {
        /* As you can see in OnCreateDialog(), this gets called for 
           frames 0 and 56 */
        if (iVocabIndex == 0) {
            tv.Text = "Show this text";
            iVocabIndex = 1;
        }
        else if (iVocabIndex == 1) {
            tv.Text = "Show this other text";
            iVocabIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    /* Must implement */
    public void ScheduleDrawable (Drawable who, IRunnable what, long when)
    {
    }

    /* Must implement */
    public void UnscheduleDrawable (Drawable who, IRunnable what)
    {
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ImageView image = view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.confDialogImage);
        tv = view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.confDialogImageText);
        image.SetImageResource (Resource.Drawable.my_animation_xml);
        AnimationDrawable b1Anim = (AnimationDrawable)image.Drawable;
        b1Anim.Start();
        Drawable d = b1Anim.GetFrame(0);
        d.Callback = this;
        d = b1Anim.GetFrame(56);
        d.Callback = this;
    }
```